# Convert recorded WAV to MP3

Tags: android, mp3, wav

Is there a way to convert WAV to MP3 in android.
My application records audio as WAV and I want to convert it to MP3 but without using 
NDK. Most answers I found is that I have to resort to using Android NDK. But I still don't know much about NDK. 
So, is there anyway to convert it to MP3. Like just some libraries or something?

Comment: so, i dont have to resort to NDK in those answers, right?

Comment: The first and accepted response lists both pure java and NDK versions.

Comment: how can i use it for my android application?